# Show an image if a query return is null SSRS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have 2 images, the first is a student profile picture which is pulled from a query as a long hexadecimal string.

I have some people who don't have a picture, they have no record in the profilepicture table.

Therefore I would like to show my 2nd image which is a generic no picture found when there is no result for the 1st image.
Image 1 has the expression `=First(Fields!stuPicture_picture.Value, "wc_stu_rds_studentProfile")`

Thanks in advance

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: How do i show the 2nd image, only when the query for image 1 returns zero rows

Comment: Use IIF to check the number of rows?

Comment: Thats my question how do i do that?

Comment: Check the docs for IIF, and check the docs for RecordCount.

Comment: Scrap that. I need it to only show when a certain row is blank as it is using a stored procedure. The colum is stuPicture_Picture. So would it be `=iif(ISNothing(First(Fields!stuPicture_picture.Value, "wc_stu_rds_studentProfile"))),true,false`

Comment: I would do this in your query and return the generic picture when there is no actual picture available, then your report does not have to do anything extra.